# The application has crashed with an uncaught exception 'org.applicationame.TiUIWebViewProxy' in 7.5.0 and 7.5.1 SDK

Tags: titanium, titanium-sdk

I am getting below error while using titanium SDK 7.5.0. Apps works well with 7.4.x. I am doing upgrade before that i want to address root cause why app is not working in latest and > 7.5.X

This is am getting for iOS simulator launch after login to app got crash and then stop working.

Nothing found [here](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-6017)

```
[ERROR] The application has crashed with an uncaught exception 'org.applicationame.TiUIWebViewProxy'.
[ERROR] Reason:
[ERROR] Invalid type passed to function
[ERROR] Stack trace:
[ERROR] 0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ee5b8db __exceptionPreprocess + 331
[ERROR] 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010dc68ac5 objc_exception_throw + 48
[ERROR] 2   Connect                             0x000000010831c35d TiExceptionThrowWithNameAndReason + 141
[ERROR] 3   Connect                             0x00000001082dc44b -[TiProxy throwException:subreason:location:] + 107
[ERROR] 4   Connect                             0x00000001082581b2 -[TiUIWebViewProxy evalJS:] + 562
[ERROR] 5   Foundation                          0x000000010a7047bc __NSThreadPerformPerform + 331
[ERROR] 6   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010edc2db1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
[ERROR] 7   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010edc2633 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 243
[ERROR] 8   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010edbccef __CFRunLoopRun + 1231
[ERROR] 9   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010edbc4d2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 626
[ERROR] 10  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001124b82fe GSEventRunModal + 65
[ERROR] 11  UIKitCore                           0x0000000119dbafc2 UIApplicationMain + 140
[ERROR] 12  Connect                             0x00000001081facc8 main + 104
[ERROR] 13  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000110350541 start + 1
[ERROR] 14  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Able to solve by adding below config in `tiapp.xml`. This legacy issue which enable javascript to run on mainthread. In later version its already handled different way.

```
<ios>
    <run-on-main-thread>true</run-on-main-thread>
    <!-- more iOS stuff here... -->
</ios>
```

Reference : https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-19682
https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/pull/7053
https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/pull/6891